# how to set TEXT to TextView of Fragment when Fragment is in Resume State?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am fetching data from the `internet` with the help of `AsyncTask` and sending that data to `Fragment_subclass` ( which `implements interface` ) using `onPostExecute()` by creating `object` of `Fragment_subclass` .

Edited :

this `textView` is inside `fragment's` layout

```
txt = ( TextView ) findViewById     (R.id.txt ) ;
```

this `oPostExecute()` is of `async_task` class .

```
protected void onPostExecute (String result)
{
    browse ob_br = new browse() ;
    ob_br.implement_it_();
}
```

`browse` is a `fragment` , which is implementing , `interface` whose name is `implement_it_`

```
public class browse extends Fragment implements implement_it_
{
    -------------------- // code ....
    public void implement_it_() 
    {
         TextView txt_1 = ( TextView ) getActivity().findViewById ( R.id.txt) ;
         txt_1.setText("hello");
    }
}
```

Edited : Error ,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.the_hindu_news.browse.implement_it_(browse.java:38)
at com.example.the_hindu_news.Async_list.onPostExecute(Async_list.java:56)
at com.example.the_hindu_news.Async_list.onPostExecute(Async_list.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
GC_CONCURRENT freed 185K, 12% free 2578K/2904K, paused 10ms+5ms, total 237ms
```

---

Actually , the problem which i was facing , is ....

i have not initialized my fragment class & i was using it like , new browse() as a passing variable so it was creating problem because every time a new variable is fetched .

Comment: @Tushar ... please see my Edited Section !

Comment: Are you commiting the fragment in Oncreat() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getActivity()` method of `Fragment` will return null until after `onActivityCreated()` is called. Thus, you can't use it where you are using it or you will get `NullPointerException`.

Furthermore, your Fragment does not belong to any Activity until you do a `FragmentTransaction` within the Activity. I suggest you read [this documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)

Comment: i have added , fragments in my activity treat it like  i want to change my activity at onResume() !

Comment: @user2147072 I really have no idea what you're trying to do, but when you create a new instance of `browse`, it's not going to give you a non-null Activity in `implement_it` unless you attach the Fragment to an Activity first.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the text value to the textView. you just follow the below code.
It is working in fragment.

public class CafeBarHome extends Fragment{

```
Button home;
TextView txt;
@Override   
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState){

    LinearLayout cafeLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cafehomefrag1,container, false);

     Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
    home = (Button) cafeLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_cafehome);
    txt = (TextView) cafeLayout.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txt.setText("Rio Web solution");
    String h = i.getStringExtra("value");
    Log.e("Second Screen", h);

    return cafeLayout;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Get the id of the TextView by

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
```

Now set the text as

```
tv.setText("Your_text_here");
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Kunal S. Kushwah ... please see my Edited section for errors .

Comment: browse.java:38 -- is it the line where you fetch the textview?

Comment: Kunal S. Kushwah  , Generally take it like , that i am setting text .

Comment: the nullpointerException at the line 38, if it is the one where you fetch the textview, shows that it does not exist as a resource there. The main problems may be 2--
1. Either your activity context is not correct (try getting the correct context)
2. Your TextView resource is undefined for the context

Comment: this way work with activity but doesn't go with fragment.